# How to travel from Kitwe in Zambia to Kabale in Uganda through the DRC

Tags: uganda, zambia, democratic-republic-congo

Has anyone recently traveled in the eastern DRC, the Democratic Republic of the Congo? I'm considering moving south to north, from, roughly, Lubumbashi to the border with Uganda.
However, it currently ain't all peaches in this region.

So, for simplicity's sake, how to travel from Kitwe to Kabale, through the DRC, using public transport? Or, perhaps more sensibly, anyone has any personal experience traveling around in this region?

Comment: Your question is pretty broad.  Are you specifically interested in personal safety?  Ease of travel?

Comment: Am not so sure if it's very broad. Specifically, I'm interested in *any* recent personal experience. So, yeah, that would include ease of travel, quality of the roads, existence of public transport, personal safety, cost of living, safety related to the current violent resurgence. I can read the guides, say the LP, but that won't tell me whether i can rely on them.

Comment: That's not really an answerable question then, if you're just looking for personal experience, as everyone's experience is different to some degree and you can't really say which is "right".

Comment: Hmmm. Not an unreasonable point in itself, in the sense that there is no *one* correct answer. I'm asking for personal experiences after all. But, then again, I'm asking what the situation on the ground is, now. In the volatile region that is eastern DRC, I would argue that the question then, in fact, is answerable. In the eastern DRC, at the moment, there is little else to rely on besides recent personal experiences.

Comment: @MastaBaba: I recommend you rephrase your question because Stack Exchange policy tells us not to allow "forum" style questions and only "Q&A" style questions. So instead of explicitly asking for personal experience, ask what factors you want to know about. The answers can still include personal experience in their effort to provide their "one right answer".

Comment: I understand the principle, but it also is a requirement that's not really useful to this particular situation. Particularly and specifically because the situation in the eastern DRC is so volatile, any recent personal experience carries significant weight. Still, allow me appease the gods.

Comment: It looks like you've made it suitable. Don't worry when you can't make a question suitable you can always come and ask us [in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) or try a good Travel forum site such as Lonely Planet's ["Thorn Tree"](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/index.jspa).

Comment: Meh. I find the Thorn Tree to be cumbersome, at best.

Answer (score 2):

Eastern Congo is affected by the rebel activities. Recent reports of rebels fighting with the army have been reported. Even [gorilla tourism](http://www.aboutgorillas.com/blog/north-kivu-rebellion-threatens-gorilla-tourism-in-congo.html) (in this region) have been affected and tourists can only for gorilla trekking in Uganda or Rwanda. Will update you when the security situation has improved in the region.

Comment: I know. Gorilla tourism has been suspended and there are occasional skirmishes in the lake Kivu region. Still, the region affected is limited to the area roughly around where the borders of the DRC, Rwanda and Uganda meet. That leaves a whole swath of land and, even, perhaps the possibility of comparitively easily travel from Lubumbashi to, say, Burundi, through the DRC.